# Import a folder as package in python

Tags: python, linux, package

I am using a linux server, but I don't have permission to install packages with `pip`, so I download the package I need : `tsfresh` from https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh, and then using `ftp` upload the unpacked folder I downloaded to the Linux server, but how do I `import tsfresh`??

I put the download folder in the path `/upload/tsfresh`, and my python working directory is in `/upload/`.

The following is the sub-folder of my folder `upload`

```
./tsfresh
./tsfresh/.github
./tsfresh/binder
./tsfresh/docs
./tsfresh/notebooks
./tsfresh/tests
./tsfresh/tsfresh
./tsfresh/docs/api
./tsfresh/docs/images
./tsfresh/docs/text
./tsfresh/docs/_static
./tsfresh/docs/_templates
./tsfresh/tests/integrations
./tsfresh/tests/units
./tsfresh/tests/integrations/examples
./tsfresh/tests/units/feature_extraction
./tsfresh/tests/units/feature_selection
./tsfresh/tests/units/scripts
./tsfresh/tests/units/transformers
./tsfresh/tests/units/utilities
./tsfresh/tsfresh/convenience
./tsfresh/tsfresh/examples
./tsfresh/tsfresh/feature_extraction
./tsfresh/tsfresh/feature_selection
./tsfresh/tsfresh/scripts
./tsfresh/tsfresh/transformers
./tsfresh/tsfresh/utilities
```

My question is : How do I import the `tsfresh` as a normal package.

Comment: You don't need admin rights to install packages.  You can install them for the current user using "pip install --user tsfresh"

Comment: But `pip` havnen't install yet and I don't have admin right to install it.

Comment: You also don't need admin rights to install pip.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
`python get-pip.py --user`

Comment: I don't have permission to save or write file into the system, I'm Read-Only user.

Comment: https://imgur.com/nndkwHr

Comment: You are missing the --user option that I included above.  It is crucial for you since you can't install to the system.

Comment: I still get the same error after I use `python get-pip.py--user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in your project folder, right? Then

```
import tsfresh
```

Will work if it has an **init.py** to make it a module.

If its not in that folder, append it to sys.path

Or just get your admin to install it.

Comment: It go well using `import tsfresh`, but when I try to use function of this package such as  `tsfresh.feature_extraction`, there will be error :
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tsfresh' has no attribute 'feature_extraction'`

Comment: Is there an __init__.py?

Comment: I import the sub `tsfresh` folder of git folder, there is init.py file, but I still can not use the function of this package.
`>>> from tsfresh import extract_features
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_features'`

Comment: It work after I install the dependencies package, but one of dependencies it must set up to work, so.....this is another dead end...........